# Date is not output via echo

Tags: php

I have a problem with the data output via echo. Using the following command, a display is off, so no date is displayed: `echo '<b>Date:</b> ' . $output->date . ' <br><hr>';`
What would be the correct syntax for outputting the date? I enter the date in the database using the following code (entries in the database are correct):

```
$StrSQL = "INSERT INTO contact (userid_fk,topic,message,date)
    VALUES (?,?,?,NOW())";
```

Comment: How are you retrieving the date from the database? Where is `$output` coming from?

Comment: what does `var_dump($output)` say?

Comment: That doesn't look like a row from the table you shared. Are you sure your `SELECT` query is correct?

Comment: Well, what is the line setting $output? Can you show is the select query?

Comment: Can you show your select statement?

Comment: Yes, but given it's not in $output, that means it's probably not selected properly or something.

Comment: I would think just adding `contact.date` in your select after the `contact.message` should work in getting the date

Answer (score 1):

$StrSQL2 = "SELECT users.username as bn, contact.subject, contact.message, contact.date FROM users RIGHT JOIN contact ON users.userid = contact.userid_fk ORDER BY date DESC";

Answer (score 0):

Found your problem! You're not selecting it from the db. You need to add date to the list of things you are selecting, or `select *`

Such as `SELECT users.username as bn, contact.subject, contact.message, contact.date FROM users RIGHT JOIN contact ON users.userid = contact.userid_fk ORDER BY date DESC`

Comment: Is the date in contact or users?

Comment: @Sha Updated my answer.